# Interchanging vectors coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, transformation

Is there any relation between two vectors with interchanging coordinates .. i.e: the x component of the first is the y component of the second and vice versa.

Comment: What you describe is a relation. What kind of other relation are you looking for?

Comment: No, if for example i have a vector s and a vector u whose coordinates are interchanged, is there any way to write one of them in function of the other ?

Comment: In a plane, it's reflection across the line $y=x$.

Comment: Of course, you take the function that flips the coordinates of the vector: $$f(x,y)=(y,x).$$. That's why I commented: you seem to have something way more concrete in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a matrix multiplication:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0 &1\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}y\\x\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Well i know it is a reflection across y=x and the matrix relation, but i was looking for a way to write the first in function of the other. For exemple if one vector has the negative values of another vector one can simply write s=-r .. likewise i was looking for a way *algebraicly*  to link the interchanging vectors.

Comment: But the equation above does "algebraicly" link the two vectors.

Comment: Well no, in some equation i have the vector *s* all i need to do is to eliminate this *s* and write instead some manipulations of *u* . I know that the above equation links the vectors but it won't be useful in my case.

Comment: I was working on the same equation but with other set of vectors *s* and *u* with the old set of vectors it turned out at last that *s=-r* but in the new set of vectors i was looking forward to get something similar but instead the vectors just  interchanged the coordinates so i was stuck.

Comment: Matrix representation won't help in here, im looking for a kind of vectorial relation so i can replace in the equation and be able to differentiate the result.